# IdentityServer4 - How to store refresh token into database using mysql.data?

Tags: persistence, identityserver4, refresh-token

I'm new at IdentityServer4. I read I need to implement an `IPersistedGrantStore` to store refresh tokens into a table like `PersistedGrants` in my database.

IdentityServer logs is the following when my native app ask for a new access token: `"refresh_token" grant with value: "{value}" not found in store`.

That's because I'm using in-memory version of the persisted grant store. So I need to store refresh token in a `PersistedGrant` table.

Therefore
in my **startup.cs** I added the following line:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();
```

and **IPersistedGrantStore.cs** is

```
public interface IPersistedGrantStore
{        
    Task StoreAsync(CustomPersistedGrant grant);

    Task<CustomPersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key);

    Task<IEnumerable<CustomPersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(string subjectId);        
}
```

So I have a **CustomPersistedGrant.cs** class

```
public class CustomPersistedGrant
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string SubjectId { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

and now I have to write the code for my **PersistedGrantStore.cs** class.
But the question is: once I have write code for **PersistedGrantStore.cs** class where I call `PersistedGrantStore.cs` class? In Identity.Server `Account/AccountController`? I didn't find any example about it without use EntityFramework, because I don't want to use Entity Framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key will be to implement `IPersistedGrantStore` using whatever backend you like, then to tell IdentityServer to use that implementation by registering the implementation in the dependency injection system.

For example, if you call your implementation `PersistedGrantStore`, then you could register the implementation like this:

`services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();`

You can see that essentially this is all that [the EntityFramework implementation does](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/57b73e081ab87df02e95a323630ad00169aa0f5c/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Extensions/IdentityServerEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L138), once you take away all the EntityFramework stuff.

Later when IdentityServer wants to persist a grant, it will get your implementation and call the appropriate method.  So you don't have to *do* anything, other than inject your implementation into IdentityServer so it can do whats needed.

Comment: Thanks. In my **startup.cs** I've registered the implementation with this line: `builder.Services.AddScoped<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();` . My goal is to persist a grant, but where's the code to persist a grant using `IPersistedGrantStore` and my `PersistedGrantStore`  in IdentityServer4. I don't found any reference in QuickStartIdentityServer project on github

Comment: That is an IdentityServer internal call.  You don't need to call the PersistedGrant store, just like you don't need to make the call when using the InMemory version.

Comment: In my `PersistedGrantStore` I implemented all interfaces member and I put a breakpoint at the beginning of every method in this class to debug. The problem is that the application doesn't break but I don't understand where I'm doing wrong. I configure my client with `GrantTypes.Code`, `RequireConsent = false`, `AllowOfflineAccess = true`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Jim, I tried several times, using an extension helper class like in [this project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/57b73e081ab87df02e95a323630ad00169aa0f5c/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Extensions/IdentityServerEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L138) or writing directly `services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, PersistedGrantStore>();`  in **startup.cs** but the first line of log is always `You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store`. Where am I mistaking?

Comment: HI @MiniDev1, Did you find the solution for this? I am also getting same kind of issue.

Comment: Hi @JaydeepJadav, yes you have to use interface of IdentityServer not your own interface

Comment: @MiniDev1: I used `IdentityServer4.Stores.IPersistedGrantStore` and implemented all methods. I also registered the strore in Startup.cs using `AddPersistedGrantStore<CustomPersistedGrantStore>()`

But still no luck. Also I am not getting any kind of error message like `You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store` but none of the method of `CustomPersistedGrantStore` is getting hit. Any idea of these?

Comment: I am using GrantTypes = ClientCredentials

Comment: With client credentials you don't need to persist authorization code, refresh tokens or stroing consent

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks for sharing the detailed link

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is kind of old and you might have already found the problem. I think your only mistake is that you invented your own interface instead of implementing:

```
IdentityServer4.Stores.IPersistedGrantStore
```

If you want to use your own CustomPersistedGrant it should derive from:

```
IdentityServer4.Models.PersistedGrant
```

otherwise you would have to wrap it somehow.